# Fleck (c#) Server Lib with web-socket-js (flash) Lib

Tags: c#, html, flash, websocket

I've been trying to get the echo server sample in [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck) (C# websocket server implementation) working with [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) (flash powered websockets for legacy browsers), and have been running into problems.

The first problem I ran into was getting the Client Access Policy uploading from port 843.  I gave up and just added some quick and dirty code to Fleck's WebSocketConnection read method...

```
        if (body.StartsWith("<policy-file-request/>"))
        {
            FleckLog.Debug("Reveived Flash Policy File Request");

            var policyFile = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?><!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM ""http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd""><cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain=""*"" to-ports=""*""/></cross-domain-policy>";
            byte[] bytes = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(policyFile);

            Socket.Stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            Socket.Stream.WriteByte(0);
            Socket.Stream.WriteByte(13);

            FleckLog.Debug("Flash Policy File Sent");

            return;
        }
```

Now it just seems to hang.  Here are the logs...

web-socket-js logs:

```
LOG: [FLASH]:[WebSocket] debug enabled 
LOG: [FLASH]:[WebSocket] policy file: xmlsocket://localhost:843 
LOG: [FLASH]:[WebSocket] connected 
LOG: [FLASH]:[WebSocket] request header:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8181
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: IVcOUW1sZkUxMGFNJ257dA==
Origin: http://localhost:6976
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Cookie:
```

From the Fleck echo server I'm getting this...

```
12/11/2012 2:38:37 PM [Info] Server started at ws://localhost:8181
12/11/2012 2:38:43 PM [Debug] Client Connected
12/11/2012 2:38:43 PM [Debug] Received:
12/11/2012 2:38:43 PM [Debug] 23 bytes read
12/11/2012 2:38:43 PM [Debug] Received: <policy-file-request/>
12/11/2012 2:38:43 PM [Debug] Reveived Flash Policy File Request
12/11/2012 2:38:43 PM [Debug] Flash Policy File Sent
12/11/2012 2:38:43 PM [Debug] Client Connected
12/11/2012 2:38:43 PM [Debug] Received:
12/11/2012 2:38:43 PM [Debug] 194 bytes read
12/11/2012 2:38:43 PM [Debug] Received: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8181
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: dgNDXk5mfWYPbVlnImYDEA==
Origin: http://localhost:6976
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Cookie:
```

Has anyone gotten these two libraries to get along?  I'm using IE 9.0, Flash 11.5.502.110, and .NET 4.0.  This sample works perfectly with web-socket-ruby/samples/echo_server.rb w/ IE 9.0, Flash 11.5.502.110, and the Fleck sample echo server works perfectly with Firefox/Chrome/etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  The Fleck regular expression used to parse the headers in the Web Socket Request were too strict and expected a newline which the flash client didn't provide.

```
const string pattern = @"^(?<method>[^\s]+)\s(?<path>[^\s]+)\sHTTP\/1\.1\r\n" + // request line
                       @"((?<field_name>[^:\r\n]+):\s(?<field_value>[^\r\n]+)\r\n)+" + //headers
                       @"\r\n" + //newline*
                       @"(?<body>.+)?";
```